# SOUNDEX function seems broken in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, soundex

The following statements return different `SOUNDEX` values in SQL Server 2012 while they produce the **same value** in SQL Server 2008:

```
PRINT SOUNDEX('BAKHSHI') --B200

PRINT SOUNDEX('Bakhshi') --B220
```

Has anyone else had this issue in SQL Server 2012 and knows how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx:

> SOUNDEX function implements the following rules: If upper-case H or
>   upper-case W separate two consonants that have the same number in the
>   SOUNDEX code, the consonant to the right is ignored If a set of
>   side-by-side consonants have same number in the SOUNDEX code, all of
>   them are excluded except the first. The additional rules may cause the
>   values computed by the SOUNDEX function to be different than the
>   values computed under earlier compatibility levels. After upgrading to
>   compatibility level 110, you may need to rebuild the indexes, heaps,
>   or CHECK constraints that use the SOUNDEX function. For more
>   information, see SOUNDEX (Transact-SQL)

So you might want to try following Microsoft's upgrade path advice. Also, SOUNDEX is collation sensitive - are your 2012 DB collations the same as your 2008 collations?